# How to enter password automatically in Webview

Tags: java, android, authentication, passwords, webclient

I am new to Java and Android and I got a question.
I think the solution is maybe very easy but I couldn't solve it.

I created an application with a WebView the thing is I want that the webview enters username and password automatically so that the user is already logged in when he starts the application.
I googled it and found something like that but it does not work

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("https://euterpe.webuntis.com/WebUntis/index.do#main");


webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient ());



class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
@Override
public void onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(WebView view,
        HttpAuthHandler handler, String host, String realm) {

    handler.proceed("Username", "password");

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hello please try this:

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByName('school').value = 'schoolname'");
webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByName('j_username').value = 'username'");
webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByName('j_password').value = 'password'");

webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.forms['login'].submit()");
```

the first line enables javascript

all other lines fill in the form and eventually submit the form.

Look at the String apostrophes please i edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but that was what I trie'd before and it does not work because it says  The method loadUrl(String, Map<String,String>) in the type WebView is not applicable for the arguments

Answer (score 0):

Though this is an old question I thought I would post my solution:

```
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);   

    webView.loadUrl("http://your.url");

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByName('school')[0].value = 'schoolname'");
            view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByName('j_username')[0].value = 'username'");
            view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByName('j_password')[0].value = 'password'");

            view.loadUrl("javascript:document.forms['login'].submit()");
        }
    });
```

It looks much alike the answer from Benjamin. Only difference is the **[0]** part, selecting the first found element, plus my implementation waits for the page to load before firering javascript at it.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient ());
```

with

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient ());
```

Only then the override method `onReceivedHttpAuthRequest` will get called.

This handling will only work for HTTP authentication requests.